# More detailed logging needed -- MimeMessage and SMTP Mail

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I've the following function which will send an email to some receivers.
The test of the function from my local machine was okay. Now I've implemented the function as part of a batch job.
The logging suggests that there might be problem with `MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);`.
The last line in my log-file is `INFO: Generate Session with Mail-Server.`

What I need are some ideas how to enhance the logging and find a reason why the function ends at the constructor.

I've tried to run the function in the terminal of the server but with the same result. The lag of information why the function terminates at the MimeMessage constructor is a bit concerning.

```
    public static void sendErrorMail(Properties prop, Logger logger) throws IOException {
    // Get the session object
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", prop.getProperty("addo.host"));
    logger.info("Mail Host set to: " + prop.getProperty("addo.host"));
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    logger.info("Try generating and sending Mail.");
    // compose the message
    try {
        logger.info("Generate Session with Mail-Server.");
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        logger.info("MimeMessage - consruction success.");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(prop.getProperty("addo.mailFROM")));
        logger.info("Mail send FROM set to = " + prop.getProperty("addo.mailFROM"));
        message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(prop.getProperty("addo.mailTO")));
        logger.info("Mail send TO set to = " + prop.getProperty("addo.mailTO"));
        message.setSubject(prop.getProperty("addo.mailSubject"));
        logger.info("Mail subject set to " + prop.getProperty("addo.mailSubject"));
        message.setText(prop.getProperty("addo.mailText"));
        logger.info("Mail text set to = " + prop.getProperty("addo.mailText"));
        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        logger.warning("Send Mail failed! Inform Business User manually.");
        mex.printStackTrace();
        progExit(prop, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your existing try block additional catch blocks for [java.util.ServiceConfigurationError](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/issues/550) and java.lang.RuntimeException.  If you are seeing ServiceConfigurationError then either the context classloader needs to be changed the batch server has the wrong JavaMail artifact like the API only version of JavaMail without the method bodies.

You can also turn on [mail debugging](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/FAQ.html#debug).  Here is an example with both changes but only apply one at a time and test each change independently.

```
public static void sendErrorMail(Properties prop, Logger logger) throws IOException {
    // Get the session object
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", prop.getProperty("addo.host"));
    logger.info("Mail Host set to: " + prop.getProperty("addo.host"));
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    logger.info("Try generating and sending Mail.");
    // compose the message
    ClassLoader cce = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(Session.class.getClassLoader());
    try {
        logger.info("Generate Session with Mail-Server.");
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        logger.info("MimeMessage - consruction success.");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(prop.getProperty("addo.mailFROM")));
        logger.info("Mail send FROM set to = " + prop.getProperty("addo.mailFROM"));
        message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(prop.getProperty("addo.mailTO")));
        logger.info("Mail send TO set to = " + prop.getProperty("addo.mailTO"));
        message.setSubject(prop.getProperty("addo.mailSubject"));
        logger.info("Mail subject set to " + prop.getProperty("addo.mailSubject"));
        message.setText(prop.getProperty("addo.mailText"));
        logger.info("Mail text set to = " + prop.getProperty("addo.mailText"));
        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (MessagingException | RuntimeException | ServiceConfigurationError mex) {
        logger.warning("Send Mail failed! Inform Business User manually.");
        mex.printStackTrace();
        progExit(prop, false);
    } finally {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cce);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I found that the Error was caused by a missing activation.jar which is needed because of a higher jdk version on the server.